# The Cloud Resume Challenge - S3 Bucket creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am working on the cloud resume challenge by Forrest Brazeal.
I am trying to deploy S3 using SAM. But when I run `aws-vault exec 'user' --no-session -- sam deploy`, I am encountering the following error.
[image]

Comment: Pick a better name, AWS bucket names need to be globally unique, e.g. append your account id or some other unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS S3 Bucket names are set globally, meaning that, for example, in your case, someone else has set **my-fantastic-website** as their bucket name in a different AWS Account. Bucket names **HAVE** to be unique

You can solve your problem by changing your bucket name to something unique, maybe adding a random number at the end or just your name